# How do I remove decimal points from y-axis in Python to make it look simpler to the reader?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

The image shows y axis in very complicated decimal points. I want them to appear as whole numbers and the scale can be written on top of the graph. How do I display it?

[image]

Code is as follows:

```
wave15_284=wave[1266:1276]-np.mean(ir1270[0:20])
ir15_284=irr[128,1266:1276]

def gauss_15_284(wave15_284, const15_284, A15_284, x015_284, sigma15_284):
    return const15_284 + A15_284 * np.exp(-(wave15_284 - x015_284) ** 2 / (2 * sigma15_284 ** 2))

def gauss_fit15_284(wave15_284, ir15_284):
    mean15_284 = sum(wave15_284 * ir15_284) / sum(ir15_284)
    sigma15_284 = np.sqrt(sum(ir15_284 * (wave15_284 - mean15_284) ** 2) / sum(ir15_284))
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(gauss_15_284, wave15_284, ir15_284, p0=[min(ir15_284), max(ir15_284), mean15_284, sigma15_284])
    return popt

const15_284, A15_284, x015_284, sigma15_284 = gauss_fit15_284(wave15_284, ir15_284)

plt.plot(wave15_284, ir15_284, 'ko', label='data')
plt.plot(wave15_284, gauss_15_284(wave15_284, *gauss_fit15_284(wave15_284, ir15_284)), '--r', label='fit')
plt.legend()
plt.ylim(0,0.0015)
plt.title('Gaussian fit for Fe XV_284')
plt.xlabel('wavelength (nm)')
plt.ylabel('Irradiance')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `plt.ticklabel_format(style='sci')`, which displays the labels in scientific notation. It displays the mantissa along the axis, and the exponent at the top of the axis.

To apply this to only the y-axis, set `axis='y'`.

Refer: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.ticklabel_format.html